# drupal how to allow logged in user to edit specific content node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a Drupal 7 site with single SSO via the LDAP module, which allows us to run the site as n Intranet and users that hit the site with IE will get automatically authenticated using their active directory credentials.

I have a personnel directory content type that holds a list of all of our employees and some of their stats (photo, email, phone number, etc.).

The problem I want to allow the logged in user to be able to edit the node in the personnel directory page that represents them, but because there is no relation between the logged in user and the nodes under the personnel directory content type I am not sure how to go about allowing users to edit their own entries?

The personnel directory page is automatically populated/updated via feeds (it looks at our AD, and pulls down users and updates them if it detects updates in AD meta data).

Somehow I need to tie the logged in user to the specific node, any idea how I could automate this as there are over 300+ nodes/users.

Ultimately, I'd like to have a "edit personnel bio" link that they can link, that will link based on their [current logged in user ID] it will allow them to edit the correct node in the [personnel directory] content type.

I hope this was clear enough to point me to some direction.

Thank you.

Comment: did you come up with a solution for this?  I'm working on a project with this same scenario, but can't seem to get anything to work.  Thought I would comment on your question before I create my own.

Answer (score 0):

basically you want to create a user "role". Then in your permissions page (the one with 1000 checkboxes) you can add edit access to your "personnel bio" content type (or fields) for just that user role.

Then in your template you provide the user a link to the same page with /edit in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user has permissions to edit the node of that type.  Upon creation of the node via feeds, create a rule (use the Rules module https://drupal.org/project/RULES) to change the creator of the node to that user's uid.

Add another field in the user's account to match their AD username to tie them together.  To do this, create a module as seen at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8253/how-to-add-extra-fields-to-user-profile